# Should we be doing homework problems that have arbitrary restrictions?

Tags: discussion

[Here is the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496471/how-to-recursively-ask-to-input-while-the-input-is-not-valid) that prompted me to write this. Initially, the question was (paraphrasing here), "How to recursively ask the user to input a number until a valid number is entered."

Two people answered and I commented, and in all three cases, the response to the OP was (paraphrasing again), "Don't use recursion for this, use a loop."

The OP responded by editing the question to add, "FYI: Looping is forbidden".

Clearly the OP is not interested in best practices. He just wants someone to do his homework for him. But as I see it, the answer that the OP wants (code that recursively prompts the user for input) has absolutely no value to future visitors to the site, or is harmful (to unsuspecting novice coders). It seems clear to me that the answers should reflect best practices, regardless of what the OP's homework assignment says.

Therefore, I downvoted and voted-to-close with this custom reason, "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the restriction that "Looping is forbidden" means that this question has zero value for future readers."

My question: Is that close reason valid, or should we post answers that do not reflect best practices?

Comment: Arbitrary restrictions don't necessarily mean it's a bad question. There are plenty of cases in reality where it's unfeasible to adhere to best practices. Homework questions are not forbidden on the site, either. If it's a bad question, downvote and move along, just like every other bad question.

Comment: The OP is partly to blame for neglecting to specify the restriction upfront, but that's a problem with the OP's behavior more than the question itself.

Comment: @BoltClock  True, but let's assume that the restriction *was* specified upfront. Do we really want questions on the site where the correct answer is, "Don't do that!". It seems problematic to allow questions like that, since the OP would never accept the correct answer.

Comment: If the OP never accepts such an answer, that's their prerogative. If they don't end up getting the help they're looking for on SO, well, I'm sure there are others who can help them...

Comment: Luckily, most such 'drive a nail without using a hammer' posts are 'do all my work for me' bad anyway. No suggestions, no algorithm proposals/choices, no code, 'plz help i dont know where to start' etc. are all nice let-outs - down/close vote, next...